# Ubuntu - SSSD - SSH key retrive from windows AD

Tags: server, ssh, sssd

I have asked my windows team who manage the active directory to add my ssh public key to my AD account.
But after the first login to my Ubuntu servers the key did not created.
Do you know which setup required in the sssd or sshd-config for the windows AD could able to create the public key on the linux host.
regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following lines required:

sshd

AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys %u

AuthorizedKeysCommandUser root

sssd

ldap_user_extra_attrs = altSecurityIdentities:altSecurityIdentities

ldap_user_ssh_public_key = altSecurityIdentities

ldap_use_tokengroups = True